# How to get the text of the selected option(s) in angular using ng-options

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

My code is here in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8TwSH/), and below is the c/p of that code. My question is how to get just the text **Mon** and not **["Mon"]** when I click on the *Monday* option, and also how to get **Mon, Thu** when I multi-select Monday and Thursday (ofc, you get the point: **Tue, Wed, Sat** when Tuesday, Wednesday and Saturday options are selected). I must be missing something obvious so please steer me in the right direction.

**html:**

```
 <div ng-app ng-controller="Controller">
    <select multiple="multiple" ng-model="day" ng-options='day.id as day.name for day in days'></select>

    {{day}}
</div>
```

**js:**

```
function Controller($scope) {
    $scope.days = [
        {
            name: "Monday",
            id: "Mon"
        },
        {
            name: "Tuesday",
            id: "Tue"
        },
        {
            name: "Wednesday",
            id: "Wed"
        },
        {
            name: "Thursday",
            id: "Thu"
        },
        {
            name: "Friday",
            id: "Fri"
        },
        {
            name: "Saturday",
            id: "Sat"
        },
        {
            name: "Sunday",
            id: "Sun"
        }
    ];    
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want. What you get is an array containing all the selected options IDs. What do you want to get instead? What prevents you from looping over the array and transform it to whatever you want?

Comment: Hi JB Nizet, thx for your comment. I'm lacking the understanding how to loop through the {{day}} variable in the html, as that would then definitely allow me to do with the array whatever I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/8TwSH/1/) that transforms the array to a String and displays it as a string directly in the page:

JS:

```
$scope.selectedDaysToString = function() {
    return $scope.day.join(', ');
}
```

HTML:

```
{{selectedDaysToString()}}
```

And here is [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/8TwSH/2/) that generates a list containing all the selected days:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="d in day">{{d}}</li>
</ul>
```